# Output of CSUM() in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

Can anyone please help me in unstanding below csum function.
What will be the output in each case. 
   csum(1,1),
    csum(1,1) + emp_no
    csum(1,emp_no)+emp_no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSUM is an old deprecated function from V2R3, over 15 years ago. It can always be rewritten using newer Standard SQL compliant syntax.

**CSUM(1,1)** returns the same as **ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1)**, a sequence starting with 1.
But you should never use it like that as ORDER BY 1 within a Windowed Aggregate Function is not the same as the final ORDER BY 1 of a SELECT, it's ordering all rows by the same value 1. Teradata calculates those functions in parallel based on the values in PARTITION BY and ORDER BY, this means all rows with the same PARTITION/ORDER data are processed on a single AMP, if there's only a single value one AMP will process all rows, resulting in a totally skewed distribution.

Instead of ORDER BY 1 you should use a column which is more or less unique in best case.

**csum(1,emp_no)+emp_no** is probably used with another SELECT to get the current maximum value of a column and add the new sequential values to it, i.e. creating your own gap-less sequence numbers.

This is the best way to do it:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column(s)_with_a_low_number_of_rows_per_value)
   + COALESCE((SELECT MAX(seqnum) FROM table),0)
   ,....
FROM table
```